# Two primary domainnames for one WebApplication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, domain

Can a SharePoint 2013 OnPrem environment handle two primary domainnames, A and B?

Reason:
Company is going to merge next year, current employees need to continue working with name A.
A new team needs to work with name B.

They do not want any migration scenarios. Once the merger is finalized workers A will no longer use name A (but login to the same environment under name B)

Comment: do you want to have URLs with 2 domains? what i am understand is: you have two domains A & B...currently user are being authenticated using domain a\user, you want add the users domian b\user into the same sharepoint farm. in future do you want to shut the domain a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can 'extend' the web application and assign the second domain to this extension.

Also see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176089/how-to-configure-sharepoint-to-work-for-2-different-domains-on-the-internet

and

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287954%28v=office.12%29.aspx